# Incorrect result of if statement in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \edef\var{1}
    \if \var= 1
    {var equal one}
    \else
    {var not equal one}
    \fi 
\end{document}
```

I try to define new variable `\var` with value `1`. Then I try to make if statement as the code above. But the result is  `var not equal one`, instead of `var equal one`. Why this can happen?

Comment: I cannot explain why - I leave it to people more competent than I -, but using `\ifnum` instead of `\if` it works.

Comment: @Iacobus1983 the `\ifnum` conditional is used to compare whether two numbers are greater than, less than, or equal to each other. Unlike `\if`, the conditional `\ifnum` needs three arguments:  the first number, a comparison operator (`=`, `<`, or `>`), then the second number. So you're right—`\ifnum\var=1` also produces the correct result.

Comment: @gz839918 thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use "raw" TeX `\if...` tests, unless really needed. They are quite complex to understand.

For example, even if [@gz839918's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691021/38080) **does** work, in this case, it can be quite... surprising the output of

```latex
    \edef\var{12}
    \if\var12
    {var equal twelve}
    \else
    {var not equal twelve}
    \fi
```

See ?

Use higher level constructs, like `\ifthenelse` offered by [the `ifthen` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen?lang=en):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
    \edef\var{12}
    \if\var12
    {var equal twelve}
    \else
    {var not equal twelve}
    \fi 

    \ifthenelse{\var = 12}{But really var is 12}{Not 12!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `\if` conditional compares whether two macros are the same after expansion. Therefore, by deleting the equals sign and using

```tex
\if\var1
{var equal one}
\else
{var not equal one}
\fi
```

you'll obtain your desired output, *var equal one*.

Comment: this would also report  `var equal one` after `\def\var{33}`

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but you misunderstood what `\if` does.

When TeX finds `\if`, it starts expanding the next tokens until finding two unexpandable ones that it eventually compares.

So with `\if \var= 1` the comparison is between `1` and `=`, which are different as far as `\if` is concerned. The `1` that follows the `=` disappears as part of the false text.

What you possibly want is `\ifnum` that again does full expansion until finding something like

```
<number><relation><number>
```

where `<number>` is anything that TeX can interpret as a number and `<relation>` is one of `<`, `=` or `>`.

If you replace `\if` with `\ifnum` you get what you expect. But you need to be very careful.

By the way, `\edef\var{1}` and `\def\var{1}` do exactly the same thing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\var{1}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \ifnum\var=1
    this is the one case%
  \else
    this is the not one case%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\foo\ and some text follows.

\def\var{0}

\foo\ and some text follows.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the `%` that protect against endlines to be considered as spaces. ***Don't*** put `%` after the `1` in the first line.

Exercise: guess where the following code fails.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\var{1}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \ifnum\var=1%
    123%
  \else
    789%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\foo\ and some text follows.

\def\var{0}

\foo\ and some text follows.

\end{document}
```

[image]